# Outlook not purging deleted IMAP messages

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I've got several hundred emails in an IMAP folder in outlook, when I delete them and then hit purge, some of them stay in the folder with little deleted icon next to them, but they are not removed from the folder.

[image: Picture of the icon]

So when i hit delete, the font gets strike-through, but when i hit purge, the only thing that happens is that little icon is displayed.  Other messages in the folder don't seem to have this issue and they are correctly purged.

Finally, when I click any messages that has strike-through and the icon, both strike-through and the icon disappear and the message is no longer indicated as deleted at all...

How can i get rid of these messages with the icon?

Answer (score 2):

What you are seeing isn't surprising if you are deleting large volumes of messages- sometimes they won't be removed from the server instantly (for a variety of reasons).

Personally I find it easier to avoid that whole issue by doing 2 things:

- [hide](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/Hide_Strikethrough_Messages_Marked_for_Deletion_in_Outlook.htm) deleted items (so strike-through messages are not even shown)
- set deleted items to be [purged automatically](http://email.about.com/od/outlooktips/qt/et_auto_purge.htm) when switching between folders- so no additional manual steps need to be taken to finish removing the emails from the server.

That way, upon hitting delete, the email instantly disappears from view in Outlook (and is also deleted from the server in the background soon after).

[image]